# Fill in numbers in order between two numbers

Tags: c#

Let's say you have two numbers, 4 and 9. The numbers can't be less than 0 or more than 9.

I want to fill the gap between 4 and 9 with numbers in correct order like so:
456789

How does one exactly do so? I've been stuck on this problem for the past 2 hours.
Thank you.

I have tried putting the numbers into an array and using the array's length as a way to fill in the numbers.

I've tried numerous other things that I don't know how to explain.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Not sure why people are upvoting this. OP has not shown any effort, has not even indicated what the expected output should be.

Comment: @DavidG at this point, I'm not sure it's people anymore...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a loop and loop thru all the integers between your numbers and add each number to a string if that is your desired output:

```
string CreateNumberSequence(int start, int end){
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = start; i <= end; i++){
         sb.Add(i.ToString());
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Note that 10-12 would produce 101112, so you might want to add some separator between numbers, or just create a list of numbers and do the formatting separatly. You could also use [Enumerable.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=net-7.0), but if you are new to programming it is useful to know how to use plain loops.

If you want a list of numbers, change `StringBuilder` to `List<int>`, remove all the `.ToString()` and change the return-type. Or just use the previously mentioned Enumerable.Range.

Comment: Not sure OP actually needs a string response, but actually not sure what OP needs at all since it's such a poor question.

Comment: You can read this for more info https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_for_loop.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the range method. since you know the start and end of the sequence you can put the start as 4 and the difference to the end from counting all the way from start will be 6.
and for 10-12 it will be like

```
var number = Enumerable.Range(10, 3);
var number = Enumerable.Range(4, 6);
var result = string.Join("", number.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enumerable.Range`

```
int start = 4, end = 10;

int[] range = Enumerable.Range(start, end - start + 1).ToArray();

// range: 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

With extension methods :

```
    public static class Ext
    {
        public static bool ToIntValue(this IEnumerable<int> source, out int output)
        {
            string joinedSource = string.Join(string.Empty, source);
            return int.TryParse(joinedSource, out output);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<int> NumbersBetween(this int start, int end)
        {
            if (start > 0 && end <= 9 && start <= end)
            {
                for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
                    yield return i;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Start and end must be beetween 1 and 9 and end must be bigger than start.");
            }
        }
    }
```

use case :

```
            if (1.NumbersBetween(9).ToIntValue(out int result))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
```